# this.state.search_results.map is not a function but it's an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects

```
render: function(){
console.log(this.state.search_results);
var renderedSearchResults = this.state.search_results.map((result) => {
```

The console.log prints:

> [{"id": "testGroup2"}, {"id": "testGroup77777"}, {"id": "testGroup1"}, {"id": "testGroup3"}]

The data is obtained through:

````
$.ajax({
        url: this.props.routes.search,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(searchObj),
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            this.setState({search_results:data});
        }.bind(this),
        error: function(xhr, status,err){
            console.error("/api/response", status, err.toString());
        }.bind(this)
        });```
````

Through:

```
def post(self):
    """
    Makes a request to search for a specific
    searchtype: Group
    searchstring: ""
    requestedfields: []
    """
    search_type = self.json_data.get('searchtype', 'Group')
    search_string = self.json_data.get('searchstring', '')
    requestedfields = self.json_data.get('requestedfields', ['id'])
    search_model = {
        'Group': Group(),
        'User': User()
    }[search_type]
    search_fields = {
        'Group': ['id', 'tags'],
        'User': ['username']
    }[search_type]
    # check if requestedfields contains valid fields
    for field in requestedfields:
        if field == 'id':
            continue
        value = search_model.default().get(field, None)
        if value is None:
            return self.set_status(400, "Model {0} does not have requested field {1}".format(search_type, field))
    try:
        search_results = search_model.search_items(search_string, search_fields, requestedfields)
    except err:
        return self.set_status(400, "Something went wrong")
    self.set_status(200, "Success")
    return self.write(tornado.escape.json_encode(search_results))
```

I'm really confused as to how `this.state.search_results` isn't an array that I can iterate through, can anyone see what's going on?

I've tried using `console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(data));` inside the success function and I get:

```
[object String]
```

Comment: try using JSON.parse(data), and see what you get.

Comment: @jamesemanon I found it out, I didn't specify the dataType in my ajax request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set `json` data type in an explicit way, while doing your ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: 'json',
  //...
});
```

Most probably `Intelligent Guess` that is used to detect data type by jQuery, is giving wrong result.

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer, didn't set dataType: "json" in my ajax request.